# Повторное использование каналов

Tags: golang

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с каналами. В примере пользователь вводит в форму число и получает квадраты чисел от 0 до этого числа. Это всё работает, но когда пользователь повторно отправит число через форму, возникает ошибка - попытка отправки в закрытый канал (*panic: send on closed channel*). Соотвественно нужно перезапускать программу.
Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли способ чтоб это все работало без перезапуска программы (переоткрыть канал и тд) ?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
)

const INDEX = `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
        <body>
        <form action="/sq" method="post" target="_blank">
            <input type=text size=5 name=count required value="">
            <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
        </form>
        </body></html>`

// Главная страница
func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, INDEX)
}

func counter(out chan<- int, count int) {
    for i := 0; i <= count; i++ {
        out <- i
    }
    close(out)
}

func squarer(out chan<- int, in <-chan int) {
    for i := range in {
        i *= i
        out <- i
    }
    close(out)
}

func printer(in <-chan int, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    for i := range in {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, i)
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", index)

    countNums := make(chan int)
    squareNums := make(chan int)

    http.HandleFunc("/sq", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        countStr := r.PostFormValue("count")
        count, err := strconv.Atoi(countStr)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        go counter(countNums, count)
        go squarer(squareNums, countNums)

        printer(squareNums, w, r)
    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

переоткрыть нельзя, но никто не мешает создать новый. просто занеси создание каналов в HandleFunc

```
http.HandleFunc("/sq", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Создаем новые каналы
    countNums := make(chan int)
    squareNums := make(chan int)

    countStr := r.PostFormValue("count")
    count, err := strconv.Atoi(countStr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    go counter(countNums, count)
    go squarer(squareNums, countNums)

    printer(squareNums, w, r)
})
```